# Symfony 6 - Routes with Attribute Annoation - How to pass route name via variable?

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony6

I am currently working on a symfony 6 project and use the attribute annotation for the routes directly inside the controller.

Example:

```
#[Route('/new', name: 'country_new', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
```

Now I would like to pass a part of the name of the route via a variable like:

```
private $routeName = "country"; 
#[Route('/', name: $this->routeName.'_index', methods: ['GET'])]
```

However this is not working and I get the following error:
"Compile Error: Constant expression contains invalid operations"

Do you have an idea if this is even possible and if so how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not specific to Symfony, actually, but to PHP attributes in general. Per the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.attributes.syntax.php):

> Arguments to attributes can only be literal values or constant expressions

However, as it relates to Symfony, if you are looking to just prefix all of the routes in a given controller, you can put a Route attribute on the class itself, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I searched for the prefix for routes and this resolved my issue. Did not know that this is a thing. If others are interestet as well, here is the link: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#route-groups-and-prefixes